# How do I load a page for each user after setting their username as a search param?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Long story short, I got an idea of how to 'give each user  their own page'. On instagram, a user's page would be https:instagram.com/{username} and on my project, its basically the same after passing the username as a url param as well as putting the rest of the data in the query so I can then call it. When I click each user's page, I get redirected to the "user's page" and I get an error that says "BadRequestError: Bad Request".

This is what happens when the user is clicked(the params are added to the url)

```
function userClicked() {
                var i = 0;
                const queryString = window.location.href;
                console.log(queryString.concat('/', username));
                window.location = queryString.concat('/', 'username=', username, '%', 'name=', fln)
            }
```

What am I doing wrong/why aren't the individual pages showing up?

Comment: Would I have to set up routes?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the post from SoftDev:

First of all, you should replace `%` with an `&`. The reason for this is that % is used for url-encoding. %20 for example might indicate a space and %21 might indicate a exclamation mark. The symbols `?` and `&` are used to indicate query parameters. Where the first query parameters would be led by a `?` and all following query paramters by a `&`.

For example: `https://stackoverflow.com/index.html?name=test&username=larssy1&age=99`

Coming once again back to (copy/paste from SoftDev) (Take note that I did change the `/` to a `?`.

```
function userClicked() {
  var i = 0;
  const queryString = window.location.href;
  console.log(queryString.concat('/', username));
  window.location = queryString.concat('?', 'username=', username, '&', 'name=', fln)
}
```

However, aside from that, it would be wise to look up the meaning of `window.location.href`. As that indicated the page currently visiting.

For example: The `window.location.href` of this stackoverflow topic is `"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734257/how-do-i-load-a-page-for-each-user-after-setting-their-username-as-a-search-para"`.

In your code, that would result in us navigating to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734257/how-do-i-load-a-page-for-each-user-after-setting-their-username-as-a-search-para/username=test&name=larssy1`

For all possible properties and meaning of `window.location`, you can refer to this w3schools page: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp or this Mozilla page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

I'm guessing you would like to use `hostname` or `origin`.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. You explained it well :). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you used '%' but it should be updated to '&'

```
function userClicked() {
                var i = 0;
                const queryString = window.location.href;
                console.log(queryString.concat('/', username));
                window.location = queryString.concat('/', 'username=', username, '&', 'name=', fln)
            }
```

Also I would prefer the following code for simplicity

```
function userClicked() {
    var i = 0;
    window.location = `${window.location.href}/username=${username}&name=${fln}`
}
```

Comment: And what was the purpose of this?